# Using Google Colab and need help in output of plotting

Tags: python, pandas, plot, google-colaboratory

I have the following code that I ran on Google Colab but I think it should plot a graph on output ! Is this right or wrong ? 
**Code:**

```
# plotting a scatter matrix
from matplotlib import cm
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

X = fruits[['height', 'width', 'mass', 'color_score']]
y = fruits['fruit_label']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')
scatter=pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(X_train, c= y_train, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, 
figsize=(9,9), cmap=cmap)
scatter
```

I am getting the output as following:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your case, I tried with sample `DataFrame` and it is displaying the graph

Comment: It works just fine with me, here is a [screenshot](https://ibb.co/ZST3ckK). I suggest restarting the Runtime and trying again

Comment: okkay , great !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all the people who tried solving my problem !
I just found out the solution.I used the following code in the beginning:

```
%matplotlib inline
plt.close('all')
```